# MySQL how to do INNER JOIN accross many columns even if some as null.

Tags: mysql

I have added this simple example, to show the problem I am having. Say this is my database foo.

```
SELECT
    `people`.`id`
    , `people`.`name`
    , `places`.`place_type`
    , `places`.`aread`
    , `family`.`family_count`
    , `income`.`income_value`
    , `income`.`average`
    , `employment`.`address`
    , `employment`.`duration`
FROM
    `people`
    INNER JOIN `places` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `places`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `family` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `family`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `income` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `income`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `employment` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `employment`.`id`) WHERE `people`.`full_name` = ? LIMIT 1
```

Now the issue here is that I get null values if `people.id` is not matching every id in the other columns. This is because not all of people with id are found in places, family, income ... columns. 
So, I would like to know how to always returns a value from `people.id` even if for example `people.id` is not same as say .. `income.id`

Comment: Not sure what you want? Do you only want to return a row if there is an entry in all tables with the same people.id?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want all records from `People table` right?? if yes then use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your joins to `LEFT JOIN` which return all the records from the `LEFT` table and only the matching from the `RIGHT` tables :

```
SELECT
    `people`.`id`
    , `people`.`name`
    , `places`.`place_type`
    , `places`.`aread`
    , `family`.`family_count`
    , `income`.`income_value`
    , `income`.`average`
    , `employment`.`address`
    , `employment`.`duration`
FROM    
    `people`
    LEFT JOIN `places` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `places`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `family` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `family`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `income` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `income`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `employment` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `employment`.`id`) WHERE `people`.`full_name` = ? LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT:** If you want to know which tables didn't have a match, just search for null values. When left joining, the tables that didn't match the condition will get `NULL` values on their column selection.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to know for example which column is missing from the result? I mean, if `family` is missing, is there anyway to know doing something like `LEFT JOIN family as f` and the in the result I could do if `empty($result['f'])` or something similar?

Comment: @ANW The ones that are missing will be selected as `NULL` values! So each column that is null from those tables (If its not null by default) means that this table is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    `people`.`id`
    , `people`.`name`
    , `places`.`place_type`
    , `places`.`aread`
    , `family`.`family_count`
    , `income`.`income_value`
    , `income`.`average`
    , `employment`.`address`
    , `employment`.`duration`
FROM
    `people`
    LEFT JOIN `places` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `places`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `family` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `family`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `income` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `income`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `employment` 
        ON (`people`.`id` = `employment`.`id`) WHERE `people`.`full_name` = ? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to know for example which column is missing from the result? I mean, if `family` is missing, is there anyway to know doing something like `LEFT JOIN family as f` and the in the result I could do if `empty($result['f'])` or something similar?